# Can Spring Roo run alongside Spring Boot

Tags: spring-roo, spring-boot

I am currently developing a Spring Roo application. The application already has quite a large codebase.

Moreover, I am very interested in Spring Boot's many features but I am not sure whether my Roo app can also run Spring Boot and if that is indeed the case what are the architectural issues to take into account in order to plug-in Spring Boot into my Roo app.

So, **is Roo compatible with Boot**?

What do I need to take into account before I undertake to add Boot to my Roo app?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576843/is-spring-boot-meant-to-replace-spring-roo

Comment: Hello and thank you Enrique! I am looking for more practical information from someone having already attempted to combine Boot and Roo and who could provide informed advice and feedback about potential issues between the two projects...

Comment: I seriously doubt there is much point in trying to combine the two. Spring Roo creates a whole bunch of Spring configuration files that Spring Boot does not need. I would hope that any new version of Spring Roo would use Spring Boot

Comment: @geoand: Thanks for your comment. Fist, Roo does not only creates configuration files but also and more importantly generates and maintains the intertype declarations. Second, many people already run Roo applications and would like to add Boot to Roo :-)

Comment: @balteo I have also used Spring Roo myself before Spring Boot came along :) That's why I gave my opinion. I think that if you already have a Spring Roo application, then porting to Spring Boot is pretty much like porting any other Spring XML based application. If you are building a new Spring application, I would go with Spring Boot, since Spring Roo generates code that is pretty outdated by today's Spring standards.

Comment: @geoand Then should I take from you comment that adding Boot to a Roo app is not that risky? :-) If so, that is good news! Thanks.

Comment: @balteo I would say that it has the same risk as adding Spring Boot to a regular Spring application with XML configuration. Also you have to know that Spring Boot requires Spring 4 to work.

Answer (score 7):

Spring Roo is useful to **generate** and **maintain** source code and to avoid to write tons of boilerplate code. It's really useful for CURD web application and I think it does not gain anything by the use of Boot.

Spring Boot is a way to help you to boost the environment configuration phase and to let you start to use your app as soon as possible. As the Spring guys say:

*Spring Boot favors convention over configuration and is designed to get you up and running as quickly as possible.*

*Spring Boot features:*

- *Create stand-alone Spring applications*
- *Embed Tomcat or Jetty directly (no need to deploy WAR files)*
- *Provide opinionated 'starter' POMs to simplify your Maven configuration*
- *Automatically configure Spring whenever possible*
- *Provide production-ready features such as metrics, health checks and externalized configuration*
- *Absolutely no code generation and no requirement for XML configuration*

If you already have an established app, I can't see real advantages to use Boot (and in any case I didn't saw a "Boot powered" app in any real production environment yet), but if you want to use it anyway you can do it without problems, just take care of these:

- Roo enrich your code through AspectJ, writing file aside by your source files, so these parts are transparent to tools like Boot
- Roo generates configuration files also, and some of them are Spring configuration files. These configuration are the same domain of work of Boot, but Boot take the precedence and can ignore them (convention over configuration) so you need to pay attention about that, and redo with Boot, using convention, the same thing Roo had already done for you but is actually ignored at runtime

For the rest, Boot integrates with Roo as with other already developed Spring app.

Answer (score 3):

I am resurrecting an old question, as the following answer will now be appropriate.

As of Spring Roo 2.0, it will generate code based on Spring Boot code. See http://spring.io/blog/2015/03/30/looking-ahead-to-spring-roo-2-0

Notably, it says:

> Create applications based on the extensive set of Spring technologies:
>   Spring Boot, Spring Data, Spring MVC, Spring Security, etc.

Currently, Spring Roo 2.0 M2 has been released.

Answer (score 0):

Both frameworks generate Spring based apps.

Said that, I see Boot as a "type of project" that Roo could generate. Note if Roo was updated to latest Spring APIs plus using Java-based container configuration, it would generate projects similar to projects generated by Boot.

Comment: Strictly Boot does not generate code, but other than that I guess I agree. Roo, if you write it today, would generate a Boot app.